How to change config of Spark worker in K8s cluster?
I have Spark standalone cluster (master and 2 workers) installed on K8s cluster from Bitnami helm chart 9.0.1 (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/spark).
I'm submitting jobs from java app (also running on K8s cluster) using "SparkLauncher" class and in Spark worker logs I can see job is submitted, but the configuration is incorrect.
In worker logs I can see launch command, which looks like this:
24/04/25 15:55:14 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/opt/bitnami/java/bin/java" "-cp" "spark//conf:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=false" "-Dspark.app.name=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.app.submitTime=1714060513205" "-Dspark.submit.pyFiles=" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "-Dspark.master=spark://my-spark-master-0.my-spark-headless.alphada.svc.cluster.local:7077" "-Dspark.jars=file:///opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.1.jar" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@10.10.6.169:37113" "/opt/bitnami/spark/work/driver-20240425155514-0014/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.1.jar" "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi"

In the command I have for example "-Dspark.driver.supervise=false", which I'm trying to change to "true".
Bitnami chart has "worker.javaOptions" and "worker.configOptions" values for this, I'm setting both, changes are visible in the worker "StatefulSet" object on the cluster, but it has no effect on the final launch command. I'm also trying to set this trough "SparkLauncher" in my Java app, but also not working. Code below.
Here is Spark worker "StatefulSet" fragment from environment, where you can see my changes are present:
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: worker
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: dle-spark
      app.kubernetes.io/name: spark
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: worker
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: dle-spark
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: spark
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 3.5.1
        helm.sh/chart: spark-9.0.1
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: empty-dir
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: spark-worker
          image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.5.1-debian-12-r2
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: SPARK_MODE
              value: worker
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: 'false'
            - name: SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY
            - name: SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT
              value: '8080'
            - name: SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS
              value: '-Dspark.driver.supervise=true'
            - name: SPARK_MASTER_URL
              value: spark://dle-spark-master-svc:7077
            - name: SPARK_WORKER_OPTS
              value: '-Dspark.driver.supervise=true'
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 750m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi

Here is my "SparkLauncher" invocation in Java code (trying both "setConf" and "addSparkArg" methods):
new SparkLauncher()
                .setSparkHome("spark/")
                .setDeployMode("cluster")
                .setMaster("spark://my-spark-master-0.my-spark-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:7077")
                .setAppResource("file:///opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.1.jar")
                .setMainClass("org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi")
                .setConf("spark.driver.supervise", "true")
                .addSparkArg("spark.driver.supervise", "true")
                .startApplication(this);

How can I influence this launch method, or config in general of my Spark workers on the K8s cluster?
